# Evaluating simple non-numeric non-exponential linear algebra expressions (so each step is referenceable)

Tags: javascript, c#, parsing, f#, abstract-syntax-tree

As the title says, I'm trying to research how to solve non-numeric non-exponential linear algebra expressions for a single variable and show the evaluation at each step until it's solved.

Ex: A+B(X+Z)/C = Y, solve for B

Ideally I'm thinking I would like it to output in a similar manner to how symbolab.com does it [here](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/A%2B%5Cfrac%7BB%5Cleft(X%2BZ%5Cright)%7D%7BC%7D%3DY%2C%20solve%20for%20B)

I have questions on a number of things:

1) How would one initialize variable constants to begin with that have no numeric value in order to be algebraically manipulable? And what type would they have? (Chars? Or something else?)

2) Does anyone have an idea of the methods symbolab is using to solve the above example?

3) I'm a fairly inexperienced coder, so before I embark on my own path, is any of what I'm asking already possible via a C# math library like SmartMathLibrary, [Math.NET](https://symbolics.mathdotnet.com/), or NCalc? Can you cite any examples that use only alphabet variables?

4) Does the fact that I don't need exponential operation (nor square roots) simplify this at all -- so that I might be able to do it in a fairly simple way?

5) Might the method solution have something to do with ASTs like in [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/254074/how-exactly-is-an-abstract-syntax-tree-created)?

And more background -- why I'm trying to learn this:

I'm working on creating an VR puzzle game in unity (for gear VR/rift/and Vive) that uses primitive math manipulatives (cubes) to teach very simple (but specific) algebra rules (isolation, substitution, and inequalities.) The manipulatives pass between two tables (literally representing the LHS and RHS of an equation)...with the intended goal of isolating one cube variable. The cubes are only manipulable using simplistic algebraic rules that the user discovers through the act of play, so nothing is spoonfed. (Whether this sounds pointless or would even be useful in the manner I've come up with is aside the point -- it's really an exercise for me to gain a better grasp at programming and because I feel VR could be an interesting means of math education -- because the program wouldn't necessarily just be for math-oriented people -- it would also be for people who struggle with the way it's normally taught, and are more visual and hands-on in their approach to learning.)

Relating to my initial question, I need to figure out how to reference the user interactions to a pre-evaluated expression (or at least, that's what I think I need to do), in order to check their progress at each step (hence my interest in how symbolab.com evaluates non-numeric variables), and allow them to step-back and forward and check their answer at each point (which corresponds to various point deductions -- unless they only check their answer when they think they're finished --at which point they'd get a bonus). It's my belief that I need to write my own behind the scenes algebra parser (hence the question), because I want the initial setup to be randomized given the constraint of the game tables (only six placements above and to the bottom of each table on either side).

[Here's a static walkthrough video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpjNtgjW6Iw) I created that hopefully demonstrates what the actual game is meant to play like (though, I realize it may still be confusing b/c it's entirely static and has no user interaction via a gear vr/rift/vive controller.)

Ultimately, I would like to make this an open-source project on GitHub that could be used in a classroom setting.

Comment: Perhaps you should familiarize yourself with the site purpose and guidelines.

Comment: You should consider/learn symbolic processing. I currently do symbolic manipulations using Prolog. While I don't use the following, it might be of help for you - [PRESS](https://github.com/maths/PRESS)

Comment: @didierc. Thanks, I just did. Before I edit my post down, the reason it has multiple questions is so far, from my research, I have yet to find the answer to any of those questions. My hope was that by asking them, I could have an inkling as to how to do this myself. I realize the answer may be similar to creating an AST and entering the CAS field -- making it more difficult for someone with my skill level, but without a lead, at this point, I'm still in the dark. Do you have any suggestions on how I should narrow the post down or simplify it?

Comment: I'm not sure whether there's a stackexchange site which handle code design questions. Now, for your questions, I would advocate to try out something, or look for existing open source projects aiming at similar goals. Basically, it's *symbolic algebra* you're trying to do, with rewriting rules to transform a formula. You could try an exhaustive search using these rules, and keep the "path" which leads to an equation with the correct left hand side, but that would be expensive. I did something similar to simplify formulas (but not in C#), and it was indeed prohibitive.